# How to change the state of form.dirty to form.prestine

Tags: angularjs, html

When submitting the form the form data have saved and Form comes in dirty state.
I want to prestine the form again. Below is the dirty state of form [image: Dirty Form]

if I use Form.prestine form comes with existing values as given below:

[image: Presting Form]

I want to set form prestine with empty fields how it can possible?
It means if once I have submitted the form next time on add button click form will open with new fields. Please help !

Comment: $scope.form.$setPristine(); should help you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `$setPristine();`
Take a look at the Angular [form.FormController docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) as well as this example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/815Bml?p=preview